# Is “I have yet to believe you were dead” grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say

> I have yet to believe you were dead

If I mean a past event? I mean he was dead but I still dont belive it.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical.

But it is very very strange.

> I have yet to believe...

This means I don't believe it now. I never believed it in the past. I might believe it in the future.  Compare "I have yet to visit France." (I never visited France, but I might in the future).  "I have yet to visit" is normal, but "I have yet to believe" is an odd expression.

> ... that you were dead.

"That" introduces a subordinate clause. "You were dead" is past tense, and implies that you were dead in the past, but are now alive.

So this means "I don't currently believe that you died and were resurrected, but I might believe it in the future".  Unless you are talking to Lazerus, I don't think you will need to say this.

I possible expression could be "I can't believe he died last night." You could use this if someone died suddenly last night, and this is surprising to you. (It is figurative language, since you can believe it. "I can't believe" is an idiom.)